# Create new ember project with no internet connection?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Can it be possible to run `ember new foo` without an internet connection?
Project initialization involves fetching a number of resources from npm; is it possible to cache these ahead of time so that an internet connection is not necessary?

Comment: I think that if you use Yarn, those things are cached and you could do it. I usually keep a recent install in a git repo though, for when I'm on a train or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ember new foo` will create the basic project scaffold as well as the `package.json` and the `bower.json`.  After that, it will install the dependencies.  You can skip that part by specifying:

```
ember new foo --skip-npm --skip-bower
```

Once you have a package.json and bower.json file, you can theoretically obtain the npm packages from elsewhere.  You can copy those folders to the application folder (`foo`) and be then be able to run the ember server.